# jQuery draggables sometimes overlap or go out of bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a grid where both rows and columns can be sorted.

I have the basic functionality in place but sometimes dragging the columns causes them to overlap.

See for example:

[image]

they shouldn't be overlapping in the second row. This doesn't happen regularly but I want to make my setup more dependable so this doesn't happen.

I tried changing the `divs` in the HTML to `ul` and `li` and I get a different bug, now the column in the second row is out of bounds:

[image]

A third bug is if I drag a row to the top left of the screen (out of bounds) it ends up moving to the end of the grid.

Here's my code, which can be played with  at http://codepen.io/maxpleaner/pen/ZLgVKN

*html(slim)*

```
div.section
  div#grid
    - 3.times do |i|
      div.grid-row
        - 3.times do |j|
          div.grid-row-item = "#{i}{j}"
div.clearfix
```

*css(sass)*

```
#grid
  width: 1000px
  min-height: 200px
  border: 1px solid darkblue
  padding: 10px
  display: inline-block
  margin: 10px

.grid-row
  float: left
  display: inline-block
  border: 1px solid red
  padding: 5px
  width: 1000px
  min-height: 50px

.grid-row-item
  float: left
  display: inline-block
  min-width: 20px
  height: 50px
  border: 1px solid white
  padding: 4px
  background-color: black
  color: white

.clearfix
  clear: both
```

*js(coffeescript)*

```
$ ->
  window.$grid = $ "#grid"
  window.$grid_rows = $grid.find ".grid-row"
  window.$grid_row_items = $grid.find ".grid-row-item"

  $("#grid").sortable()

  $(".grid-row")
  .draggable
    connectToSortable: $("#grid")
    revert: true
    revertDuration: 0
  .sortable()

  $(".grid-row-item")
  .draggable
    revert: true
    revertDuration: 0
    connectToSortable: $ ".grid-row"
```